# does TCP randomly select a time from an interval to decide when a timeout has occured?

Tags: networking, tcp, timeout

In TCP how is the time for a time out to happen determined? I was told it is randomly selected from an interval that doubles after each time out, but nothing I found on Google mentions anything about random selection and instead says it's calculated used Smoothed Round Trip Time after the first acknowledgment is received. Does it do this for each packet or is there some randomness to the design?

Comment: A doubling algorithm is frequently used to prevent congestion with repeated (likely to fail) attempts though to my knowledge, a network interface can attempt to resend however it wants. However, this is a very low level behavior.  Timeouts that you see when using sockets will be your network interface trying resends at intervals (these are transparent to the programmer), and eventually giving up when it goes for some number of minutes without receiving any response.  This user-visible timeout is also implementation dependant (though some implementations will give you the means to control it).

Answer (score 1):

An initial value of the RTT is calculated during the TCP 3-way handshake that starts a connection.  It is updated thereafter when qualifying send/acks are seen.

Most modern implementations don't use this method directly but rather using a statistical analysis of the maximum time it should take to get an ACK and retransmit after that interval.  The "exponential backoff" (the doubling of the wait interval) happens for further retransmissions of the same data.

A connection "times out" after some number of transmissions with no ACK being received.